# Inspect in Chrome is not clickable

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

I am trying to right click in Chrome and click "inspect" but it is greyed out.. I am seeking help on how to enable the inspect option.

[image: Inspect option in context menu is disabled]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that for some reason you have developer tools disabled.
Open the registry editor and set the key `DeveloperToolsDisabled` from 1 to 0, or delete the key.
The path in Windows 10 is
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome`

Note that if you are under a work network there may be a security policy that sets this key automatically.